# create a df from another one based on the first and last occurance of the 1 in the df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df and I want to get through it with a window of size 4 and build a dataframe with 1 row and same column as input. At each window,
from the first index which the first 1 is appeared put 1 until the last index which we have 1. And if in a window we dont have any 1, only put 0.
I wrote a code like this, however it does not fill the last three column correctly! Can you help me with that?
here is the input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Ids'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['a1'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a2'] = [0, 0, 1]
df['a3'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a4'] = [0, 1, 1]
df['a5'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a6'] = [0, 0, 1]
df['a7'] = [1, 0, 0]
df['a8'] = [1, 0, 0]
df['a9'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a10'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a11'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['a12'] = [0, 0, 0]
```

here is the code:

```
def max_event_time(df,window_size):
    

    output_df = pd.DataFrame()
    

    for i in range(0, df.shape[1]-window_size, window_size ):
        
        window = df.iloc[:, i + 1:i + 1 + window_size]
        
        first_index = (window.iloc[:, 1:] == 1).idxmax(axis=1)
        
        last_index = (window.iloc[:, 1:] == 1).iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)

        first_index_pos = window.columns.get_loc(first_index.values[-1])
        
        last_index_pos = window.columns.get_loc(last_index.values[0])

        df_w = window.iloc[0:1, :]
        
        df_w.iloc[:, first_index_pos:last_index_pos + 1] = 1

        df_w.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        output_df = pd.concat([output_df,df_w], axis=1)

    return output_df
```

```
max_event_time(df, 4)
```

and here is the output I want:

```
   a1   a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  a10     a11     a12
0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
```

my function does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to handle the zeros in the last block correctly, e.g. by adding

```
if window.to_numpy().sum() == 0:
   output_df = pd.concat([output_df, window.head(1)], axis=1)
   continue
```

Then

```
print(max_event_time(df, 4))

  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  a10  a11  a12
0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0    0    0    0
```

Modified function:

```
def max_event_time(df, window_size):
    output_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(0, df.shape[1] - window_size + 1, window_size):

        window = df.iloc[:, i + 1:i + 1 + window_size]

        if window.to_numpy().sum() == 0:
            output_df = pd.concat([output_df, window.head(1)], axis=1)
            continue

        first_index = (window.iloc[:, 1:] == 1).idxmax(axis=1)
        last_index = (window.iloc[:, 1:] == 1).iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)

        first_index_pos = window.columns.get_loc(first_index.values[-1])
        last_index_pos = window.columns.get_loc(last_index.values[0])

        # Make a copy to avoid modifying the original df
        df_w = window.iloc[0:1, :].copy()

        df_w.iloc[:, first_index_pos:last_index_pos + 1] = 1

        output_df = pd.concat([output_df, df_w], axis=1)

    return output_df
```

However, note that it would be better to replace the for loop by vectorised calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code:

```
def max_event_time(df, window_size):
output_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, df.shape[1] - window_size + 1, window_size):
    window = df.iloc[:, i + 1:i + 1 + window_size]

    first_index = (window.iloc[:, 1:] == 1).idxmax(axis=1)
    last_index = (window.iloc[:, 1:] == 1).iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)

    first_index_pos = window.columns.get_loc(first_index.values[-1])
    last_index_pos = window.columns.get_loc(last_index.values[0])

    # Make a copy to avoid modifying the original df
    df_w = window.iloc[0:1, :].copy()  

    df_w.iloc[:, first_index_pos:last_index_pos + 1] = 1

    output_df = pd.concat([output_df, df_w], axis=1)

return output_df

result = max_event_time(df, 4)

print(result)
```

The issue was with **iloc**, which aligns the indices based on the original DataFrame. That causes problems when you try to assign values back to the output_df

Comment: Thank you. The results of this is same as my code.